# SQL Error in Delphi: Current Provider does not support returning multiple records from a single execution

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-7

I am trying to add a field into a database with the following code:

```
        adoquery1.Close;
        ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
        adoquery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO tbllogin (txusername, txpassword, link, full_name) VALUES ("' + e1 + '","' + e2 + '","' + cb2 + '","' + e4 + '");';
        adoquery1.Open;
        adoquery1.Close;
```

e1, e2, e4, and cb2 are variables used.

This is an example of the query:

[image: This is an example]

This is the error I get:

[image: This is the error I get]

Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider

I do not know how to sovle this error any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would probably help if you told us what the "Current Provider" is that you're using. "SQL" simply indicates the language you're using to query the data; it tells us absolutely nothing about the database engine you've connected your ADOQuery to that is being sent the SQL. "My car won't work. What dealership should I take it to for repairs? It has four tires!" without knowing what kind of car it is isn't likely to get you help.

Comment: Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SELECT` is the only statement that should be used with `ADOQuery.Open`, as it returns a row set by choosing rows and returning them.

`INSERT`, 'UPDATE', and 'DELETE' (along with `CREATE`, `DROP`, and `ALTER`) don't return rowsets, and therefore you should use `ADOQuery.ExecSQL` instead.

```
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    adoquery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO tbllogin (txusername, txpassword, link, full_name) VALUES ("' + e1 + '","' + e2 + '","' + cb2 + '","' + e4 + '");';
    adoquery1.ExecSQL;
```

Also, **please** do some research on **SQL Injection** here, and stop concatenating your SQL. Learn to do it properly with parameterized statements in the first place. It's not only much more secure, but it provides much better performance from the DBMS. The proper way to write the above `INSERT` would be something like this:

```
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    adoquery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tbllogin');
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('(txusername, txpassword, link, full_name)');
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('VALUES (:txusername, :txpassword, :link, :full_name)');
    ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('txusername').Value := e1;
    ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('txpassword').Value := e2;
    ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('link').Value := cb2;
    ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('full_name').Value := e4;       
    ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: "and stop concatenating your SQL". It's partially Delphi's fault with making it so dang long to enter parameters. It's 2013; why can't it just take a dictionary?

Comment: @alcalde: It's not Delphi's fault. Write your own wrapper that accepts a dictionary if you want one. Bad programming practices are bad programming practices, and blaming the language is simply making excuses. (And your comment has nothing to do with the question asked, or my answer. This is not a discussion site or forum. If you have comments/suggestions/criticisms of Delphi, please post them in the Embarcadero forums instead.)

Comment: @KenWhite A good language makes the best thing to do the easiest thing. A poor language makes a poor thing to do the easiest way to do it. In this case the best thing is also the hard way. And exploring why a problem exists or understanding why people come here with the same problems time and again is the first step to preventing those problems, which is even more useful than fixing them after they've been encountered.

Comment: @alcalde: This has nothing to do with the language; it has to do with the code being written. You can write bad code in a good language, just like you can write good code in a bad language. It's the developer's responsibility to learn the proper way to do things. People come here all the time with the same problem in lots of areas; by your logic, the proper solution is to make everyone use the same language, and limit what can be done in that language so nothing can go wrong. There's nothing wrong with the language here.

Comment: @KenWhite And so the developers of the language don't have any responsibility? Language design is offered as a specialization in many computer science masters and doctorate degrees today because it is so difficult. Sure you can write bad code in a good language. That doesn't mean a language shouldn't make it as hard as possible to do so. If a language - actually, any library - makes it hard to do use it the best way and easy to use it unsafely, that's a suboptimal design. By my logic, we should spot "language smell" and work to fix it - or in Delphi's case, file QC suggestions.

Comment: @KenWhite Nothing wrong with the language? They never refactored the data handling components after introducing iteration in 2005 and genetic dictionaries in 2009. Uwe Raabe wrote code on his website that added both query result iteration and ability to reference result fields without all the FieldByName boilerplate, so it can be done; it just has been neglected. You can't look at other languages that allow one to pass a dictionary in for parameters, making the code readable, vs. Delphi needing many lines of code for the same process, and say there's nothing wrong here.

Comment: @alcalde: OK, so by your logic no one should write code in C because it allows you to use pointers and be responsible for your own memory cleanup? I disagree vehemently. It's the programmer's responsibility to learn the proper practices for using the language they choose. If you can't do so, you need to find a different occupation (or use a different language). The fact that Uwe wrote the code is not evidence of anything, any more than the existence of any other code is proof the language should natively include it.

Comment: Nevertheless, the point here is that the poster is cultivating bad habits **in the language they've elected to use**, and that should be discouraged. If you have suggestions to make about the evolution of Delphi, the proper place is QC suggestions (as you've indicated already you're aware of) and not in a comment here, which is simply noise.

Comment: @KenWhite "By my logic" and by standard texts on language and API design which I don't have the space to quote here, making the right thing to do the hard thing to do or an unsafe practice easier is bad design. The fact that Uwe wrote the code is evidence of something: that's it's been possible to implement for 9 years and EMBT simply don't ever revisit or refactor the standard library. You're arguing that we should have iteration but NOT be able to iterate through query results? It's a plain case of not bothering to update the standard library with new advances.

Comment: @KenWhite There have been some similar QC suggestions made by TeamB members dating back to 2005 that have simply had no response. Nothing comes of QC suggestions, unfortunately.

Comment: @alcalde: I thought this discussion ended a month ago. But... If QC suggestions from TeamB aren't working, what in the world makes you think complaining in a comment here is going to accomplish anything except adding clutter and noise here? As I said, **this is not the place that will alter anything**, and it's irrelevant to the question asked.